# How to open the facebook login page in mobile using javascript sdk?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

This is my html page, where I added a class button to click to pop up the facebook login browser

```
 <button class="fb_login">Login with Facebook</button>
```

This is my js page, where I indicate upon clicking, the function to execute, which is the getting of login status of facebook

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
        FB.init({
            appId: '',
            cookie: true,
            xfbml: true,
            version: 'v2.10',
            oauth: true,
            status: false,
        });

        $(".fb_login").click(function () {
           FB.login(checkLoginState);
            //FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
            //statusChangeCallback(response);
        });
    };
```

Now, all these works when I'm simulating it in google chrome, but when I run it on my mobile, I'm facing issue popping up the login dialogue when pressing on the button, may I know what should I do? I did some research and I saw some codes on using windows.open, but I'm not sure how to use it and is it possible to put the function inside windows.open?

Comment: Share code in the post.

Comment: `FB.login();` will anyway ask you to login !! nothing wrong in it. To get facebook login status you need to call `FB.getLoginStatus` function.

Comment: I have that function included already, everything is working fine on the web but not when i run it on mobile, meaning when i click login via fb in the web, i can do it but when i click login via fb in my mobile the login browser does not pop up...

Comment: @NeonelMessi may be popup gets blocked in mobile browser ! can u check that ?